# JComboBox - out of bounds exception

Tags: java, swing, vector, jcombobox, indexoutofboundsexception

i have a small problem. I'm trying to import logins from my database to a vector and then to use that vector for JComboBox. My method for downloading logins :

```
public void loginReader (Vector<String> loginy, String tableName)
{
    String query = "select login from " + tableName;

    try {

        Statement statement = mConnection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) 
            {
             Vector<String> vstring = new Vector<String>();

                vstring.add(rs.getString("login"));


                loginy.addAll(vstring);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
}
```

That's in class DatabaseManagement. I made another class (GUI) and there's that JComboBox. Why it doesn't work ?

```
package DataBase_Hospital;



 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.text.ParseException;
 import java.util.Properties;
 import java.util.Vector;

 import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JComboBox;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
 import javax.swing.JTextArea;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;


 public class Message extends JFrame implements ActionListener {



JButton SEND_MESSAGE;
JButton READ_MESSAGE;
public JLabel background;

JLabel NAME_LABEL;

JTextField NAME_FIELD;

JTextArea DATABASE_FIELD;
static Vector<String> loginy = new Vector<String>();

private static DatabaseManagement DATABASE;

public Message() {



    setSize(290, 500);
    setTitle("Message Panel");


    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    JLabel background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/Users/Dominik/Desktop/messageFrame.png"));
    add(background);


    DATABASE_FIELD = new JTextArea(3,3);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(DATABASE_FIELD);
    scrollPane.setBounds(45, 50, 200, 200);
    background.add(scrollPane);
    DATABASE_FIELD.setEditable(true);


    NAME_LABEL = new JLabel("Odbiorca :");
    NAME_LABEL.setBounds(40, 380, 140, 20);
    background.add(NAME_LABEL);

    SEND_MESSAGE = new JButton();
    SEND_MESSAGE.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Users/Dominik/Desktop/sendMail.jpg"));
    SEND_MESSAGE.setBounds(75, 270, 60, 60);
    background.add(SEND_MESSAGE);
    SEND_MESSAGE.addActionListener(this);
    SEND_MESSAGE.setToolTipText("Send message");

    READ_MESSAGE = new JButton();
    READ_MESSAGE.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Users/Dominik/Desktop/jwj.png"));
    READ_MESSAGE.setBounds(150, 270, 60, 60);
    background.add(READ_MESSAGE);
    READ_MESSAGE.addActionListener(this);
    READ_MESSAGE.setToolTipText("Read message");


  JComboBox loginList = new JComboBox(loginy);
  loginList.setSelectedIndex(loginy.capacity());
  loginList.addActionListener(this);
  loginList.setBounds(145, 380, 100, 20);
  background.add(loginList);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Message window = new Message();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
    DATABASE.loginReader(loginy,"uzytkownicy");
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    Object EVENT_SOURCE = e.getSource();
    DATABASE = new DatabaseManagement("pacjent");

    if (EVENT_SOURCE == SEND_MESSAGE) 
    {
        DATABASE.sendMessage(DATABASE_FIELD.getText(), "uzytkownicy", NAME_FIELD.getText()) ;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you gave us the problem with your code.

Comment: Full stack trace with any other error tidbits would help.

Comment: I inserted my code, what's wrong ?

Comment: the message after compilation is :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setSelectedIndex: 10 out of bounds
 at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(JComboBox.java:622)
 at DataBase_Hospital.Message.<init>(Message.java:83)
 at DataBase_Hospital.Message.main(Message.java:92)

Comment: The stack trace says exactly where the error is and what variable is triggering it.

Comment: Just a comment, your use of the DB leaves you open to SQL injection (if the table name can contain data from the user). Use PreparedStatements.

Answer (score 2):

After creating your `JComboBox` with your empty `Vector`, you set the `selectedIndex` to `loginy.capacity ()`. The problem is that while the capacity of your `Vector` is 10 (as stated in the [JavaDoc for the default constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#Vector%28%29)), it's actual size is 0. Hence the `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. You should check for the size of your `Vector` before setting the selected index of your `JComboBox`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is you are trying to set the selected index of your combo box to the capacity of your vector.

```
loginList.setSelectedIndex(loginy.capacity());
```

From the docs `.capacity()`:

> Returns the current capacity of this vector.
>   Returns:
>   the current capacity (the length of its internal data array, kept in the field elementData of this vector)

This is not the size i.e. the number of logins in your database. this is the capacity of internal datastructure which will always be >= the number of elements in the vector.

Try using `Vector#size()` but you will still need to subtract one (provided there is actually data in the vector) from this so your code should be:

```
loginList.setSelectedIndex(loginy.size() - 1);
```

And this will set the last login in the comboBox. Which is not required in your case as you are populating the vector after creating the combobox so you could just remove this line from your code until you populate the vector.

---

**Edit** as per comments

All you should need to do to have the logins is reorder the execution order. I.e populate your vector then create your combo box, Change your main method to something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //First initialise your database (dont do this in the action performed method)
    //  you should only need one and not need to create a new one on each action
    DATABASE = new DatabaseManagement("pacjent");
    // Read logins (I assume this is the method that does it)
    DATABASE.loginReader(loginy,"uzytkownicy");
    // Then create your message window...
    Message window = new Message();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man ! Now program starts but when i click in my ComboBox just nothing happens ... End also :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at DataBase_Hospital.Message.main(Message.java:96)

Comment: That is because you are populating the vector with your data AFTER constructing the combo box, You'll need to update the combobox with the data after reading logins from the database

Comment: Ok i understand that, but i don't know how to change that . Any suggestion ?

Comment: You can either populate the vector before constructing the combobox, so read from the database before creating the gui. Or when you read from the database add all the items to the combocbox using the comboxes addItem(item) method

Comment: Could u help me more ? I'm trying to do that but i don't know how. Could u write the correct code ? Thx !